# Scipy imsave and imread change format

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, image-formats

When I save the image, the format it has is `numpy.uint16`, when I load it, it is `numpy.uint8`, and it messes up the whole pipeline for me. How do I prevent this from happening?

I am calling

```
from scipy.misc import imread, imsave
image = imread(path)
imread(image_path)
```

Comment: Are you writing a JPEG? If so, it is inevitable as that is inherently 8-bit. Try using a PNG or TIFF or NetPBM PAM/PPM, all of which support 16-bit samples.

Comment: I am using tiff data, and I want to preserve 16-bit format. Any additions to the solution below, or you think it works fine?

Comment: I am not sure why you would accept an answer that writes to 8-bit JPEGs when you explicitly want 16-bit TIFFs...

Comment: But do you know how I can deal with 16-bit tiffs effectively?

Comment: I don't understand. That's what my answer below shows.

Comment: @BaronYugovich Assuming that `img` is a numpy array of type `uint16`, this should still work as follows: `imageio.imwrite('img_saved.tif', img)` and `img_read = imageio.imread('img_saved.tif')`. To confirm, you could check the output returned by `img_read.dtype`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `imsave` and `imread` methods are deprecated and will be removed in future versions of SciPy. Using `imageio.imwrite` and `imageio.imread` instead should solve this.

```
>>> import imageio
>>> img = imageio.imread('img.jpg')
>>> img.dtype
dtype('uint8')
>>> imageio.imwrite('img_saved.jpg', img)
>>> img_read = imageio.imread('img_saved.jpg')
>>> img_read.dtype
dtype('uint8')
```

Comment: "Using `imageio.imsave` ... should solve this" -- that function does not exist. Do you mean `.imwrite`?

Comment: @nh2 - yep; editing that part of the sentence to match the code

Comment: @nh2 it's pretty weird, this does work `imageio.imsave('hello.jpg', maps,vmax=1,vmin=-1)` however, I can't find any documentation!

Answer (score 0):

I would write and read 16-bit greyscale data to and from a TIFF like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Make a greyscale image of random 16-bit ints in range 0..65535
arr = np.random.randint(0,65535,(320,240), dtype=np.uint16)

# Make PIL image from numpy array and save
im=Image.fromarray(arr).save("result.tif")

# Re-read from file
reloadedim  = Image.open("result.tif")
reloadedarr = np.array(reloadedim)

# Calculate difference
diff = arr - reloadedarr
print("Number of different pixels: {}".format(sum(diff.ravel())))
```

It prints *"Number of different pixels: 0"*.